# Adobe Air Android / Arabic text issue

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

i'm using Adobe Flash Air for IOS & Android problem now is the Arabic RTL i can't write arabic.
My

> Input Text is Classic not " TLF Text "

The TLF problem is the keyboard not showing up in android..

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDKWO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Did you try doing some research? I googled [**`as3 "android" keyboard not showing`**](https://www.google.co.uk/?#q=as3+%22android%22+keyboard+not+showing).
What's wrong with solutions suggested on first page results of the above link?

2) Consider using [**`Stage text`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html) and there's an introduction [**article**](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/09/native-text-input-with-stagetext.html) about it.

3) Try something like below (untested) as a starting point. Hard to fix your code since none shown.

Also read this [**guide**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS82181550ec4a666a39bafe0312d9a274c00-8000.html#WS19f279b149e7481c-4cb7e4a013321c24dab-8000) first. Might be useful.

```
var testInput : TextField = new TextField();
testInput.needsSoftKeyboard = true;
testInput.type = "input";
testInput.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusText);

stage.addChild(testInput);

function onFocusText( e:FocusEvent ):void
{
    testInput.requestSoftKeyboard();
}
```